# What happens when you finish Google's Rubik's Cube Doodle?

Tags: google-doodles

On May 19th 2014, Google added [a solveable Rubik's Cube Doodle](https://www.google.com/logos/2014/rubiks/rubiks.html).

I'm not very good solving Rubik's Cubes, and couldn't solve it myself. What happens when you solve the Doodle?

If anyone looks for the keyboard shortcuts, here they are:
[image: Rubik's Cube shortcuts]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Found a video on youtube:

When you solve it, it displays the date, how many moves it took, the amount of time and your name.

Answer (score 6):

[image]

The controls are weird, so I clocked in at almost four and a half minutes, but it's still pretty fun. :)

Comment: It's interesting to note that the application moves around a little in 3D space as you move the mouse around.